# Firestore How to make a transaction without read operations?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set two documents inside a transaction using the javascript API. I tried the following:

```
db.runTransaction(function(transaction) { 
    return transaction.set(doc1Ref, doc1).set(doc2Ref, doc2);
})
```

But this isn't valid, I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction callback must return a Promise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition transactions in Firestore are updates to the data based on an existing value. What you're looking for is not a transaction, but a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).